# calculate difference for a column moving from one value to another sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables:

table1

```
item_id, sent_from, received_by, month, value
```

table2

```
item_id, sender, value, month
```

Values for sent_from, received_by, sender are the same type and format.
Data is like the following:

table1

```
values ('1234','A1111','K0000',1,5)
values ('1234','K0000','K0000',2,5)
values ('1234','K0000','Z0000',3,10)
```

table2

```
values ('1234','A1111',5,1)
values ('1234','K0000',10,2)
values ('1234','Z0000',20,3)
```

I'm trying to reconcile between table1 values and the difference in values from month to preivous month in table2. For instance:
value for month 3 in table1 should be 10 which is the same value that comes from the difference between the value from month 3 - 2 in table2. So 20 - 10 = 10. Then 10 - 5 = 5 then 5 - 0 should be 5 and so on. The impact_value from below should be the same as the values in the table1.

The following is the code I have but it's not working propery and is not computing the right values:

```
select sls.item_id,
       sls.sent_from,
       sls.received_by,
       sum(case when prd.sender = sent_from then -1 * prd.value
                else prd.value
           end) impact_value,
       sls.mnth
from   table2 prd
       inner join tabl1 sls on (prd.item_id = sls.item_id
                                and (prd.sender = sls.sent_from
                                     or (prd.sender = sls.received_by
                                         )))
group by sls.item_id,
         sls.sent_from,
         sls.received_by,
         sls.mnth;
```

However, the impact_value field is not populated with the right values like in the logic.

**EDIT:**

insert the following into **table1**:

```
values ('1234','K0000','Z0005',4,40)
values ('1234','BBBBB','ZZZZZ',4,60)
```

and insert the following into **table2**:

```
values ('1234','K0000',60,4)
values ('1234','BBBBB',120,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic or window function lead can help you get the result you are looking for

```
select t.*, lead(value) over (order by item_id, month) lead_value from table2 t;
```

Above query returns results like below, you can use it as sub query in the join:

1234    A1111   5   1   10

1234    K0000   10  2   20

1234    Z0000   20  3   (NULL)

Here is the query to get the output 10, 5, 5:

```
select t.*, value - nvl(lead_value, 0) from (select t.*, lead(value) over (order by item_id, month desc) lead_value from table2 t) t;
```

Comment: Those are not the results im looking for. The value should be: 10, 5, 5

Comment: select t.*, value - nvl(lead_value, 0) from (select t.*, lead(value) over (order by item_id, month desc) lead_value from table2 t) t;

Comment: this does not work if i add new entries in the tables, please see EDIT section in the question. Thank you :)